# How can I get Request Parameter of this below code in JSON Format For Logging it into Db

Tags: laravel

```
$result = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => config(''),
        ])->post($endPoint, [
           "username" => '',
           "password" => '',
            // "username" => $user->username,
            // "password" => $user->password,
            "days" => 7
        ]);
```

In this code I want to save the request and request parameter in JsonFormat for logging into mysql db.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel testing
https://laravel.com/docs/master/testing

or

Postman offers a sleek user interface with which to make HTML requests, without the hassle of writing a bunch of code just to test an API's functionality
https://www.postman.com/

Comment: I want to save it in mysql database the request i sent from my application and parameters along with this request.

Comment: In this code i am sending request to my api for data fetching. I want to log this request in my db mysql.

Comment: https://github.com/yadahan/laravel-authentication-log

Comment: Thanks man this link help to solve my problem.